# How to fix "undefined reference to:" in arduino ide, trying to use googletest

Tags: c++, arduino, googletest

I am trying to use the googletest library to test code in the arduino ide, and I keep getting errors such as

> In function __static_initialization_and_destruction_0' undefined
>   reference to `std::ios_base::Init::Init()'

There are 50 more lines of this error, including

> undefined reference to testing::Test::SetUp()' undefined reference to
>   testing::Test::TearDown()

Since even the basic test functions are failing, I assume I made a mistake in where I put my library files, or perhaps I'm simply not including the correct files.

Currently I am only including `gtest/gtest.h`, as that is all I have seen in other examples in order for the code to work.

I have built the googletest library using cmake and make, and included it within the project.

Does anyone have an idea of what I can do to fix this?

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the [help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named How to Ask. You might also want to learn about [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Arduino does not use the STL, are you sure you can use googletest for arduino projects?

Comment: Since what Narase said is true, none of the regular C++ libraries you find in the wild are guaranteed to work for the Arduino, only those in the Arduino library library.

Comment: Code for microcontrollers are generally not unit tested (or only rather small parts are which do not touch any microcontroller registers or functions). Personally I wouldn't because you often make coding decisions which reduce unit-testabiity but increase performance/reduce code size for the microcontroller. I think you would be better off doing some functional testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't compile googletest in the Arduino IDE. Primarily because the compiler used by the Arduino IDE is meant to generate (for normal arduinos) `AVR` binaries not `x86`/`x86-64` ones. These `AVR` binaries can't be ran on a normal PC and are only meant to be ran on the embedded platform. Because on the embedded platform the normal standard text IO streams are not available the arduino IDE doesn't include the standard IO used on normal PC's for terminal use. (aka pipes 0 1 2 on unix).

> I have built the googletest library using cmake and make, and included it within the project.

It is correct that this isn't going to work. If you compile googletest with cmake/make you are probably building a `x86` or `x86-64` binary which you are then including in the arduino IDE. The arduino IDE compiler is then going to try to link an `AVR` binary to a `x86`/`x86-64` library. This is not going to work.

I would recommend you design your software in such a way that the hardware dependent logic is removed from your business logic if you do want to test your Arduino code with googletest. The business logic can then be unit tested by compiling a ('normal') `x86` or `x86-64` binary with the test code which can be ran on a normal pc. This will involve mocking up the hardware interfaces used in your code. This build infrastructure can easily be set up inside the same structure of your arduino project and testing will only involve building a test binary and running that.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I was hoping that there would be some way to make them compatible without mocking all of the hardware, but now it sense that wont be plausible.

Comment: If answer is a good answer and/or the accepted one then please [vote the answer up and/or accept it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). This rewards both you and me and makes it clear to others what the best answer is.

Answer (score 0):

> Google test has been used on a variety of platforms:
>
> - Linux
> - Mac OS X
> - Windows
> - Cygwin
> - MinGW
> - Windows Mobile
> - Symbian
> - PlatformIO

No Arduino, no Microcontroller